# Rails Nested Object API using swagger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, swagger, swagger-ui, nested-resources

I am using swagger to describe apis in rails application. I have two model in rails. One is author and another is books. There is one to many relationship between books and author. An author can have many books. I want to create a new author with some books. For that I wrote this code

```
swagger_api :create do
  summary "Create new author"
  notes 'Create new Author with multiple books.'
  param :form, :name, :string, :required, "Author name"
  #Here books will come
  # Then some responses 
end
```

How do I define these books Here. So I can add multiple books using swagger UI.

Answer (score 1):

If you have in your Author class:

`has_many :books
accepts_nested_attributes_for :books`

Then you can do something like:

`param :form, 'author[book_attributes][title]', :string, :optional`

Comment: what to do if your number of object for has many are dynamic .sometime it has one record and sometime 2..n

Answer (score 1):

[Nitin Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1776627/nitin-jain) Try to use:

```
param :form, 'author[book_attributes][][title]', :string, :optional
```

Comment: if you use it, then form of swagger generated docs send this params:
{ author: { book_attributes: [ { title: 'Test' } ] } }, and then you can save it by standard rails way

Answer (score 0):

Responses above began work for me only when I change `book_attributes` to `books_attributes`. But anyway thanks a lot, guys!